# Scrape data the first span instance of same div class name

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to scrape the data of the first span instance of divs with similar names in Python using BeautifulSoup (BS4). Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="network-ctn animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
                <h3>Network Overview</h3>
                <div class="networkstat-ctn">
                    <div class="networkstat"><span>32</span><span>Games</span></div>
                    <div class="networkstat"><span>83,681,202,831.85</span><span>Award</span></div>
                    <div class="networkstat"><span>18</span><span>Top players</span></div>
                </div>
</div>
```

The HTML above code is from a website, I just copied the portion from which I want to scrape the data. For example my scraped data should look like:

32

83,681,202,831.85

18

I am new to Python data scrapping & I've tried the code below but failed:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find_all("div", class_="networkstat")
value1 = div[0].find("span").get_text().strip()
value2 = div[1].find("span").get_text().strip()
value3 = div[2].find("span").get_text().strip()

print(value1, value2, value3)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `css selectors` to select the first span child of div:

```
for e in soup.select('.networkstat span:first-child'):
    print(e.get_text())
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="network-ctn animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
                <h3>Network Overview</h3>
                <div class="networkstat-ctn">
                    <div class="networkstat"><span>32</span><span>Games</span></div>
                    <div class="networkstat"><span>83,681,202,831.85</span><span>Award</span></div>
                    <div class="networkstat"><span>18</span><span>Top players</span></div>
                </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for e in soup.select('.networkstat span:first-child'):
    print(e.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks, I just run the code as you said but I don't get an output nor an error...

Comment: Example is based on your question and it is working, so there must be something wrong in the way you try to request the html, but this is not part of your question and should be asked as a new one with exact this focus.

Comment: Yes, it seems like there is a problem with the request. I've run your code with local HTML and it works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

your code should work. the only problem is this `requests.get(url).content,` - you use `.content` but you should use `.text` 
try this `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')`

Comment: `.content` is for getting media files like video, if you need to parse txt data from html you've to use `.text`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the content to text but I get an error: ```value1 = div[0].find("span").get_text().strip()
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: it means that `div` is empty and `div = soup.find_all("div", class_="networkstat")` finds nothing

Comment: I've just copied your code snippets to my sublime, tried it and it works

Comment: But the div(s) contains the data inside Span(s)?

Comment: 'div is empty' I mean not html's divs but the `div` your variable in your code

Comment: that variable `div` is empty and that's why you can't index it with [0]

Comment: maybe it's because the website gives you different html, it's better to save that html any to test your parsing code on the file saved on your computer

Comment: check if the html is still the same == print `requests.get(url).text`

Comment: Yes, seems like there is a problem with the request.

Comment: maybe website doesn't like a lot of requests and it can give you a captcha instead of html you need